# Data dependencies and caching

Tags: python, dependency-injection, functional-programming, dependencies

I have a complex python function which computes a level based on various sub functions and data dependencies.

What are the best ways to control the data dependencies and have reproducible calculations?

The data can come from external data bases and data sources, so potentially they can change when the code is run multiple times.

Currently i am using the following approach: wrap all data access into an accessor class that caches all data that it requests. The accessor object is a global variable, hence at the end of the calculation i can look up the state of my cache.

This gives me reproducibility: If i want to rerun the calculation with the exact same data i just force the accessor function to directly retrieve data from the cache.

One drawback is that this approach forces the use of a global variable.

An alternative would be to inject the data dependencies directly into the functions parameters, but i dont know upfront the dependencies or even their structure, as branching in my code can depend on data.

Does anyone know better alternatives or references for that topic?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Decorate, decorate, decorate. Especially in Python - with more or less native [support for that](https://peps.python.org/pep-0318).

However, that's not a cache. The fact that you store something in RAM and avoid further calls that potentially would read updated data is not enough to call it a "cache". The latter is - no more, no less - an *optimization mechanism*; it helps to keep the system performance good enough - and that's it. On the contrary, you are talking about state initialization issues within the context of a concurrent system that is subject to change at any moment.

From what you wrote I deduce you lack a context. Since you explicitly tag your quest as related to the `functional-programming`, I would focus on its common sense and well-recognized patterns.

The first thing that comes to mind is Haskell. Both because of type classes (which do not exist in Python and you shouldn't try to implement them yourself, that would break the philosophy of the language and wouldn't play out well with the rest of the libraries out there). Yet Haskell is still an insightful source of inspiration. There you are given a [State Monad™](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) and a `do` notation, which allows you to achieve your goals while also avoiding a global state: you'd just perform an `IO` (within another monad) and then initialize your (non-global) state monad instance with it and ensure that rest of the computation runs **within its context**. The closest Python-native thing I imagine is something alike:

```
with MyDataContext(...) as dc:
    state = dc.read_state() # makes sure to read the right data
    ...
```

That does not have to be global yet would allow you to keep your code within the given data context (for whatever it might mean concerning your domain of which I know nothing).

The other approach is plain old decorating. Given a function `get_data()` that performs some IO and retrieves bytes over a network, you could have implemented a trivial decorator, say, `once(get_data)` that would produce another function **of the same interface** but with slightly different behavior - namely, short-circuiting subsequent calls. A typical Python code of that sort would look somewhat similar:

```
import functools
import time

import requests  # pip3 install requests

@functools.cache
def get_data(num):
    res = requests.get('google.com')
    return res.body
```

Then your decorators can go arbitrarily smart: for example, nothing stops you from examining the function's args and acting differently based on that. Another typical strategy is to take what environment are you running in into consideration and behave differently in a debug/test mode by producing more logs and serializing your entire data snapshot to a persistent storage for future reuse. Note that decorators are easily testable by themselves - with no effort at all you are welcome to mock `get_data` with `get_fake_data` and ensure your decorator does the job.